# query the average requests completed in a year\month\week\day

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query built below on the total amount of requests created in a year grouped by the task name (c.status_text) and the year they were worked(a.finish_date).  In the SR_WORKFLOW table in my query below, there is a field called 'assigned_to' which is the employee number of the user that finished a ticket.  I need to find the average number of requests our employees complete in a year/month, etc grouped by the task name (c.status_text).  If I can figure out how to write this query for a year, I should be able to do the rest of them.  So essentially what I am doing is trying to count the number of employees that have worked a specific task and then get the average number of tasks a person worked.  Sorry if that sounds confusing.  If so I will try to explain better.

I am able to get the totals of each employee id but that is over 5000 lines of results and does not give me an average.

```sql
select count(*) as [Total SRs],
       c.status_text,
       DATEPART(YEAR, a.finish_date) as [Year]
from SR_WORKFLOW a 
inner join SR_SERVICE_REQUEST b on a.sr_id = b.sr_id
inner join WORKFLOW c on a.WORKFLOW_GUID = c.WORKFLOW_GUID
where b.type = 'Fed Wire'
and a.finish_date >= '2018-01-01'
and a.assigned_to is not null
group by rollup(c.STATUS_TEXT, DATEPART(YEAR, a.finish_date))
order by c.status_text
```

Comment: Made some progress.  Found the total number approvers for each task.  So all I need to do is to be able to divide the first column by the fourth column to get a new column with a result.

Comment: ```sql
select count(*) as [Total SRs],
       c.status_text,
       DATEPART(YEAR, a.finish_date) as [Year],
    count(distinct a.assigned_to) as [Total number of approvers]--,
    --sum(count(*) / count(distinct a.assigned_to))
from SR_WORKFLOW a 
inner join SR_SERVICE_REQUEST b on a.sr_id = b.sr_id
inner join WORKFLOW c on a.WORKFLOW_GUID = c.WORKFLOW_GUID
where b.type = 'Fed Wire'
and a.finish_date >= '2018-01-01'
and a.assigned_to is not null
group by rollup(c.STATUS_TEXT, DATEPART(YEAR, a.finish_date))
order by c.status_text

Comment: sorry not sure how to add code tags for SQL

Comment: These are different things but you write like one follows on from the other: *So essentially what I am doing is trying to count the number of employees that have worked a specific task and then get the average number of tasks a person worked*

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't post code in comments.